# Android magnetometer returning random values

Tags: android, accelerometer, compass-geolocation, magnetometer

I am building an Android application which logs the degrees of the compass of the device into a file. There are two methods the get this degrees:

**Method 1:**

```
SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor orientationSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, orientationSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);


public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float azimuthInDegrees = event.values[0]
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor accelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
Sensor magnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

float[] mGravity;
float[] mGeomagnetic;

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
       mGravity = event.values;
    }


    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
        mGeomagnetic = event.values;
    }

    if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
        if (success) {
            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);   

            float azimuthInDegress = ((float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]) + 360) % 360;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried out both methods by placing my device in the North direction (which is around 360 degrees):

**Method 1** returns perfect results but unfortunately this method is deprecated:

- 359.6567
- 359.5034
- 359.859
- 359.76212
- 359.8878
- 359.87048
- 359.8356
- 359.80356
- 359.81192
- 359.7671
- 359.84668
- 359.88528

**Method 2** also returns good results but sometimes (randomly) it returns an incorrect degree:

- 359.91495
- 359.83652
- **263.67697**
- 359.67993
- 359.70038
- 359.688
- 359.71155
- 359.70276
- 359.6984
- 359.6429
- **270.6323**
- 359.62302
- 359.49954
- 359.44757
- 359.47803
- 359.4947
- 359.39572

As you can see, some incorrect degrees are randomly returned with the second method. The device is calibrated and I think that the problem is with the second method as the first method returns perfect results. Can you guys help me out?

Comment: what position is the device when you get these result. for example holding the device straight up

Comment: I'm holding it in my hand. Almost flat

Comment: Just change ? = event.values to event.values.clone() for now and see if you still get the same behavior.

Comment: Wow man, that worked. Why is that so?

Comment: because if you set mGravity = event.values, you set mGravity to a pointer, the value at the address the pointer point to can change.

Comment: This happens quite a lot so let me write up as an answer so that other people with similar problem would easily notice it instead of having reading all these comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the assigment of `mGravity` and `mGeomagnetic` it should be `event.values.clone()`. mGravity has class scope but, by using mGravity = event.values, you assign its value to a value in an address that has method scope. So as soon as onSensorChanged is called again and it is magnetic type, the mGravity is now pointing to a variable which no longer exists and thus can have any value.